# Oracle regular expression

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have below string of data,How to get number alone using oracle regular expression last two charcters is always either 'RC' or 'RN'.If number not found return
0.

```
1AEABCRC

1AEABC1RC

1AEABC1RN

1AEABC2RN
```

Comment: Is the expected output 1, 11, 11, and 12 for the four rows of sample data that you posted?

Comment: OK.  Then you'll have to help us out a bit.  What is the algorithm that you want to implement?  I see numbers in the first position of all 4 strings.  Do you want to exclude numbers in the first position?  Do you want to exclude numbers that are in leading positions in the string?  Do you only want to look for numbers that are in the third to last position?

Comment: i have to omit the string "1AEABC" first then before RC if there is any integer it should retun otherwise 0

Comment: If that is the case, why are the last two strings not 0?  There is no `RC` so there is nothing before `RC` to return.  Perhaps you meant "before `RC` or `RN`)?  Do you really just want to check whether there is a number at the 7th position of the string?  Or at the third position from the end?

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   nvl(regexp_substr(column_name, '(\d*)(RC|RN)$', 1, 1, null, 1), 0)
from table_name;
```

Comment: +1, didn't know about the `subexp` param, though this answer is good only for 11g

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
select nvl(regexp_replace(regexp_substr(v, '\d+(RC|RN)$'), '(\d+)(RC|RN)$', '\1'), 0)
from t;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46a3c/24)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.  Dunno if you want the number as a number or are willing to work with as a char, but:

```
select nvl(substr(regexp_replace('1AEABCRC','^1[A-Z]+'),1,1),to_char(0,'9')) from dual;
select nvl(substr(regexp_replace('1AEABC1RC','^1[A-Z]+'),1,1),to_char(0,'9')) from dual;
select nvl(substr(regexp_replace('1AEABC1RN','^1[A-Z]+'),1,1),to_char(0,'9')) from dual;
select nvl(substr(regexp_replace('1AEABC2RC','^1[A-Z]+'),1,1),to_char(0,'9')) from dual;
```

Of course you can replace the string literal with a column name or variable or somesuch.  Won't work if the number goes to two digits, obviously.